# My docker compose files in different projects are interfering JetBrains IDE

Tags: java, docker, intellij-idea, jetbrains-ide

If you're having trouble with docker-compose.yml deploying from wrong project

Answer (score 0):

[image: Youre having your configuration in project A, as always it's named docker-compose.yml]

You're creating docker configuration in project **B** and deploying it, you realize that it's been deployed a file from project **A**

**Solution:**
[image: Edit your docker configuration]

[image: Add new configuration]
[image: Specify path to your docker-compose.yml from project B and deploy that config only]